# Add into SQL Server table a relative path of an image stored in my project folder, then recover it into my program C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, relative-path

I have a database table which also has a column of type `image`. The definition of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_battery]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [capacity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [image] [image] NOT NULL, -- -----------<HERE IS IMAGE>------------
    [price] [float] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_table_battery] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The insert statement is:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table_battery] OFF

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_battery] ([capacity], [description], [image], [price]) 
VALUES ('Value1', 'Value2', 
        (SELECT BulkColumn 
         FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Ingeniería Informática\2 año\2º Cuatrimestre\Programación Visual Avanzada\ProyectoFinal\AJMobile\AJMobile\scr\images\bateria.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS CategoryImage), 
        'Value3')
```

And as you can see, here is full path. I want to do something like:

```
(SELECT BulkColumn 
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'.\..\..\scr\images\bateria.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS image)
```

But I do not know how can I achieve this.

Also, I have read that if you stores in database an image with relative path, It is sure you will get trouble when you will try to recover it from the datatable... So I would like to know how can I get it into my C# application for using it without problems.

Thank you.

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Not sure about it, but I think what you are trying to do is not possible. when you run the query, sqlserver don't know what is the "currentDirectory" , (I mean, what it should consider as a start folder in order to navigate upwards with `..\..`...)

Comment: Ok,  @marc_s. Thank you for the advice,  I Will take it in care

Comment: Oh,  really? @Gian Paolo... And there is no trick to get this neither?

Comment: @marc_s I have been searching about varbinary... Could you answer the question with an example? It has not been very clear to me at all, I'm starting in databases and SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you would like to have SQLServer to load the file.
This can be quite a difficult scenario to handle: sql server cannot use relative path as you like.
moreover, it can happen that you sqlserver is not able to access the file you are trying to load: what if sqlserver is running on a different pc? what about file access right? (check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#security-considerations) for some further info about this problem)

Since it seems you are calling the query from a c# application, it's much easier to have your application load the file, and pass its content as parameter to the query;

Something like this:

```
void Insert()
{
    string query = @"
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_battery]
       ([capacity], [description], [image], [price]) 
    VALUES 
       (@capacity, @description, @fileContent, @price)";

    // setup values you want to use for the query
    int capacity = ... ;
    string descr = ... ;
    float price = ...;

    string path = ... // you can use relative or absolute path here
    byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    SqlConnection conn = null;// get connection some how;
    using (conn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@capacity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = capacity;
            command.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = descr;
            command.Parameters.Add("@fileContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = fileContent;
            command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Float).Value = price;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

*(disclaimer: not tested and not compiled, may require some edit)*

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the answer. When I arrive home I will try this, I will comment you if it is working. Does it matter to use relative or absolute paths as you comment? And .. when I want to recover the photo, I do not have to worry about whether they are relative or absolute? Also say that there you enter the route as varbinary instead of image, it's equivalent, right? Thank you.

Comment: with this code (and with your original SQL code) you are saving on db the file content of the file, not its byte, so when later you will read the saved record, you will not have any reference to the original file location . This solution allow you to handle the loading of the file in the c# application, instead of asking sqlserver to load it. In the c# code, you can use absolute or relative path, as long as it identify the same file.

Comment: Oh, ok, thats is perfect!!. Also, is there any command for doing that directly in SQL? Something like: `INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_battery]
       ([capacity], [description], [image], [price]) 
    VALUES 
       ('Value1', 'Value2', (convert my_path to varbinary), 'Value3')` ?